# Importing phonegap project

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

So I received the source code of an app I want to enhance. The app was developed with phonegap, so I downloaded phonegap and tried opening it, but all I can see is the following, and when I click the arrow to open it, nothing happens. How can I correctly open this project??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> click on arrow then it will turn onto  green color . Then in the
>   footer it will show some link to the server where it will run your
>   poject .

Or

> Just create a new project using phonegap then replace its www folder
>   and config.xml file .

Comment: That's the thing... i click the arrow and nothing happens

Comment: it didn't turn into green  ?